# Mocking RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rhino-mocks

I have a paging controller with a method which calls

```
RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(this.viewContext.RequestContext, valueDictionary)
```

I am trying to test this method using Rhino mocks and I'm unsure how to mock GetVirtualPath to return a route other than null. I am mocking the RequestContext but I am unsure which methods/properties need to be stubbed.

By stubbing the mockRequestContext appropriately should GetVirtualPath return a non null path, and if so what needs to be stubbed for this to work?

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand you question, but it looks like something like this:

```
IRouteTable routeTableMock = RhinoMocks.CreateMock<IRouteTable>();

// assuming that IRouteTable.Routes is of type IRoutes.
IRoutes routes = RhinoMocks.CreateMock<IRoutes>();

// return the routes with the mock
routeTableMock.Stub(x => x.Routes).Return(routes);

// setup the mock for GetVirtualPath
routes.Stub(
  x => x.GetVirtualPath(
    Arg<RequestContext>.Is.Anything, 
    Arg<IDictionary>.Is.Anything)
  .Return(/* whatever */);
```

if this is not what you are looking for, you have to tell more about your classes and what yo want to test.

Comment: The class has a viewContext passed during construction which is then used in a call to RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath. This is called on the Sytem.Web.Routing.RoutingTable.RouteCollection class. Is there a way to stub the ViewContext so the call on Sytem.Web.Routing.RoutingTable.RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath will return a path?

Comment: Oh, this is something completely different, sorry. When you mock the ViewContext, you need to know what calls are made by GetVirtualPath. If ViewContext is a rather complex thing, you should consider to mock the whole stuff away.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that was my question - what calls are made by GetVirtualPath to enable me to mock the ViewContext in a way GetVirtualPath will return a value.

Thanks for your input though - I guess I could put the GetVirtualPath behind an interface to remove the dependency for testing? Seems overkill for this simple case though...

Comment: if it is really that simple, you don't have to test it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the complete virtual path, but just the URL it generates, you can instead use:

```
new UrlHelper(ControllerContext.RequestContext).RouteUrl(routeValueDictionary)
```

... and mock out the ControllerContext:

```
var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

var controllerContext
    = new ControllerContext(
        mockHttpContext.Object,
        new RouteData(), 
        new Mock<ControllerBase>().Object);

var myController = new MyController { ControllerContext = controllerContext };
```

I was having this exact problem but this appears to have solved it.